# "Error database connection" message even though I configured the localhost website with the correct settings

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I installed Xampp, created a data base and named it "wordpress".

I have edited the wp-config.php file with the following settings:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress'); 
define('DB_USER', 'root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here'); 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

But when I attempt to access `http://localhost/wordpress/` I'm greeted with "Error database connection", even through I've used the correct settings. What is the problem?

Comment: Why would you edit the config before installing WordPress? is this a fresh install or not?

Comment: I just installed xampp on my computer. But am a newbie in webmastering now, so I don't clearly understand how to fix this error. I didn't edit the config before installing WordPress. Before I edited it I created a database in phpMyAdmin, only then I went to xampp- htdocs- wordpress- wp-config.php and edited it. Then I tried to open wordpress site in browser.

Comment: Thank you for you help, Simon. I have already fixed it.

Comment: Awesome! I've deleted the comment and left it as a answer. Happy WordPressing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made it complicated on yourself... delete the wp-config.php file then go to `http://localhost/wordpress/` and use WordPresses inbuilt installer, this will setup the database and install what is needed to it.

You DO NOT need to edit the wp-config.php file. This is what the installer does for you and it populates the SQL database with all the required tables.

Answer (score 0):

go to phpmyadmin and to your DB and see privileges ... you should give the user All Grant privileges ...
go to : phpmyadmin > click on your DB > privileges > edit privileges of the user > check all > click on GO